# Why my page does not render correctly only in mobile?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="MsgBody" style="width: 90%;align-self: center;margin: 3vh 0;flex-direction: column;display: flex;">
    <div class="MsgRight" style="flex-direction: row;width: 50%;align-self: flex-end;justify-content: flex-end;display: flex;">
        <div class="MsgSendContent" style="background-color: #9eea6a;border-radius: 5px;padding: 10px;word-break: break-word;flex-shrink: 0;display: flex;">
555        </div>
        <div class="RightTriangle" style="margin-top: 8px;width: 0;height: 0;border-style: solid;border-width: 7.5px 0 7.5px 10px;border-color: transparent transparent transparent #9eea6a;flex-shrink: 0;margin-right: 8px;display: flex"></div>
        <div class="HeadImg RightHeadImg" style="background-image: url(/img/testhead.jpg);height: 40px;width: 40px;border-radius: 5px;background-position: center;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;flex-shrink: 0;display: flex;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In PC end, it runs well:
[image]

In the Chrome Toggle device toolbar, I tried all the device and all of them works well also.

Well, when I run the page in iPhone 6s with Chrome of IOS 13.1.2, it turns out to be this:
[image]

As you see, the message dialog does not render correctly and the input box in the bottom miss yet.

Then I tried the safari and the problem still here. What's more, I tried an android device which is android 9, the input box does not miss any more but the message dialog still does not render correctly.

The problem only occurs in the mobile device but not in the Chrome Toggle device toolbar. I can hardly know how to debug and solve it.

I should not only post a URL here but I don't know where is the problem.

Would you please help me to solve this and tell me why it doesn't render identical even I use Chrome in PC and Mobile.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it might be related to the face you are using flex-box which is not 100% supported by this browser.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @EladBash In the website you provided, it said ios 13.1 supports it well yet.

Comment: For a proper answer, you need to provide a [mcve], **within** the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your page is not responsive 
Integrate bootstrap ,so you don't have to write CSS files manually and use pre build  classes with bootstrap grid to make responsive pages 
There are several tutorials available for bootstrap I prefer you to go through them 
My personal favourite is:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Comment: This is not an answer. We do not know what OPs code looks like. Posting a link as an answer is also not acceptable. Also, bootstrap is not required for responsive web development and may be too much for OPs needs.

Comment: Also better is the offical documentation for bootstrap. But as @disinfor says bootstrap is not required for responsive development you can also write your own css with media queries for example